# Power BI create column with condition

Tags: powerbi, dax

My direct Query structure img

[image]

I want to create a column in `FB_DATA_AD_ONLY` to get the `VALUE` of `FB_ACTION_AD` where the `ACTION_TYPE="something"` in power BI. I should keep the function " direct query". Do you think I can do this in Power BI ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would suggest looking at these site to understand the limitations of Direct Query (I know that I don't know all of the limitations).

- [Use DirectQuery in Power BI Desktop](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-desktop-use-directquery/)
- [Using DirectQuery in Power BI](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-desktop-directquery-about/)

Second, in the first one, it talks about a setting you can turn on to bypass some of the limitations Power BI imposes on Direct Query. To turn that option on, go to File -> Options and settings -> Options, then go to Direct Query and check the box next to Allow unrestricted measures in DirectQuery mode (Power BI will need to be restarted after checking that option).

[image: Direct query setting]

With that option checked, you can create some new measures in the data. I have some basic sample data (created using this [SQL script](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ae143e052063033cd4061f960a972804)).

[image: Schema]

Click on the ellipses ("...") next the your `FB_DATA_AD_ONLY` table (I'll be using my `Buildings` table) and select `New measure`. Enter the following formula

```
NewMeasure = CALCULATE(
    SUM(FB_ACTION_AD[VALUE]),
    FILTER(
        FB_ACTION_AD,
        FB_ACTION_AD[ACTION_TYPE] = "something"
    )
)
```

I used this formula.

```
EmpSum = CALCULATE(
    SUM(Employees[idemp]),
    FILTER(
        Employees,
        Employees[FirstName] = "Alex"
    )
)
```

I threw together a quick table and matrix to illustrate that the measure is returning the expected value (Alex is only assigned to one building and their ID is 2, so that building would have a EmpSum value of 2).

[image: Results]

Comment: thank you a lot the secret is allow unrestricted measures in DirectQuery mode :)